# Right Triangle Segments

Tags: geometry

A right triangle is divided into two smaller triangles when an altitude is drawn toward the hypotenuse. If the distance between the incenters of the two smaller triangles is is 14, find the inradius of the original triangle.

(Rickards Invitational 2012)

The radii of the two circles r different right? I'm not so sure, so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Altitude $\overline{CF}$ divides right triangle $\triangle ABC$ (with hypotenuse $c$) into right triangles $\triangle CBF$ (with hypotenuse $a$) and $\triangle ACF$ (with hypotenuse $b$).

[image]

These triangles are similar, so corresponding lengths are proportional. In particular, if $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are incenters as shown in the diagram, then
$$|\overline{FX}| : |\overline{FY}| : |\overline{CZ}| \quad=\quad a:b:c$$

Now, since $\overline{FX}$ and $\overline{FY}$ bisect adjacent right angles (why?), they themselves form a right angle. Therefore,
$$|\overline{XY}|^2 = |\overline{FX}|^2 + |\overline{FY}|^2 = \left(\frac{a}{c}|\overline{CZ}|\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{c}|\overline{CZ}|\right)^2 = \frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}|\overline{CZ}|^2 = |\overline{CZ}|^2$$

so that $|\overline{CZ}| = |\overline{XY}| = 14$.

Since $\angle C$ is a right angle, the inradius of $\triangle ABC$ is easily obtained from $|\overline{CZ}|$.